# React components does not re-render when only a subset of the state is mapped to props

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to figure out why subsetting the state causes the a react component not to re-render when that subset changes. Here is my code:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {bindActionCreators} from 'redux';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {PieChart, Pie} from 'recharts';


class MyPieChart extends Component{
    render() {
        var data = [
            {name: 'var1', value: this.props.myData['var1']},
            {name: 'var2', value: this.props.myData['var2']}
        ]

        return (
            <PieChart width={800} height={400}>
                <Pie data={data} cx={200} cy={200} innerRadius={70} outerRadius={90} fill="#82ca9d"/>
            </PieChart>
        );
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state, props) {
    return {
        myData: state.components[props.component]
    }
}


export default connect(mapStateToProps)(MyPieChart);
```

The render function is not triggered when `myData` changes.
The reducer setting `myData` is triggered by a movement on a slider.

However, if I change my `mapStateToProps` function with:

```
function mapStateToProps(state, props) {
    return {
        myData: state.components[props.component],
        state: state.components
    }
}
```

then everything works fine and the component renders every time I change the value on the slider.

So my question is: Can you use a subset of the state inside a component, or is there a way to only give it the info it needs.

In my case, this would re-render every time a value somewhere in the app is changed, which would not be the best performance-wise i would guess.